# How can I get a list of all tables in database with selected prefix?

Tags: mysql, list

As in subject title.
My database contains a huge amount of auxiliary tables.
Would like to build a dropdown list to select table I would like to load content from.
This code ... does not work:

```
SELECT table_name FROM sys.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'Mytable_%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mysql you could access  to information_schema  filter your db name

```
 SELECT table_name 
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE table_schema = 'your_db_name'
 and table_name LIKE 'Mytable_%'
 and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

Comment: You must add **AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'** in your query else you also gets VIEWS,....

Comment: @BerndBuffen   correct  ... answer  updated  with your suggestion too ...many thanks

Comment: Great thanks, still getting some things ... useless :(

Comment: @RobertA.  what do you need  to filter  more ??   .  add a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: One sec, got no error but returning "0" while I have more than 100 tables with prefix Mytable_

Comment: Great thanx! :)